# Sometimes my shared folder disappear and I have to do a hard reboot

Tags: hard-drive, share

In my home network I have a RPi3 connected by USB to a 3Tb hard disk. I can access both RPi and a shared folder that lives on my hard disk.

I mounted this hard disk on `/mnt`. My shared folder is `/mnt/krash/share`.

What happens is that sometimes (a lot) my shared folder disappear and I can't access it using `ssh`. Sometimes even RPi disappears of my home network. If I do `sudo reboot` nothing happens after that.

The only way to get access to my shared folder is by disconnecting and connecting RPi.

Comment: when you say the pi disappears from the network, meaning you can no longer ping its IP address?  After restarting the pi, you should check system logs to see if there is any indication of what is happening.

Comment: Most of the times when I do `ls /mnt/nameofdisk/` I obtain nothing instead of `lost+found share`.

Comment: that probably means the disk is not mounted, do you see the disk name when you run "mount"

Comment: May be but I can't test it now because the disk is mounted. But what happens is that without any apparent reason the disk unmounts itself.

Comment: Did you check system logs to see if there was any indication of why?

Comment: No. I will do it when it happens again.

Comment: Are you using Samba/CIFS or NFS for sharing?

Comment: I am using samba.